# build XML format from JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I'm trying to generate an XML format based on my JSON, not trying to convert it from JSON to XML.

An example of JSON I'm trying to generate to XML

```
var jObj = { "Smart Shoes":{  
      "Product":"Smart Shoes",
      "Price":24.99,
      "Quantity":"1x "
   },
   "Denim Jeans":{  
      "Product":"Denim Jeans",
      "Price":30,
      "Quantity":"1x "
   }
}
```

Trying to generate XML in a format like below.

```
<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true">
 <commands>
  <injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR"/>
  forEach(Item in Basket) {
    <injectdata type="literal" data="{Item.UPC}"/>
    <injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC"/>
  }
 </commands>
</xml>
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/J3inh8v09Yrvyt5SI6ma?p=preview)

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? In the browser? locally? nodeJS? an XML database?

Comment: browser, the xml get generated `onclick()`.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript (or jQuery) to directly create your XML elements in a DOM-style fashion.  This approach I feel is better than creating a string because this method will handle proper format and encapsulation.

Here is a JavaScript example:

```js
var jObj = { "Smart Shoes":{  
      "Product":"Smart Shoes",
      "Price":24.99,
      "Quantity":"1x "
   },
   "Denim Jeans":{  
      "Product":"Denim Jeans",
      "Price":30,
      "Quantity":"1x "
   }
};

var xml = document.createElement("xml");
xml.setAttribute("id","POSCMD");
xml.setAttribute("LateProcessing","true");
var commands = document.createElement("commands");
xml.appendChild(commands);
var injFM = document.createElement("injectfieldmacro");
injFM.setAttribute("type","field");
injFM.setAttribute("name","FIELD_CLEAR");
commands.appendChild(injFM);
var injData;
for (var item in jObj) {
    injData = document.createElement("injectdata");
    injData.setAttribute("type","literal");
    injData.setAttribute("data",JSON.stringify(jObj[item]));
    injFM = document.createElement("injectfieldmacro");
    injFM.setAttribute("type","field");
    injFM.setAttribute("name","FIELD_UPC");
    commands.appendChild(injData);
    commands.appendChild(injFM);
}

// Append XML to DOM
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(xml);
```

I just wrote the code to stick the JSON object data into the data field, because it wasn't really clear about how you were trying to proceed.  However, the code below should at least provide enough information to expand upon if you would want/need to split the data into multiple "injectdata" XML elements.

**Edit:** I edited the snippet so the XML gets appended directly to the DOM body tag.  When you run the snippet, if you right click on the iframe and inspect, you should see these elements actually put in the DOM:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Why not use string like the other answer?

Comment: There is more than one wait to achieve this.  Making a string is the most basic approach.  It is "quick and dirty" and it works.  The issue is that string formatting can get messy and convoluted.  The way your question was worded, it sounded to me like you were looking for an option that wasn't building a string.  Native JavaScript DOM functions can be used to make XML as well.  Also, the function at the end was just to convert the XML into a format to print to the browser to show you how it looks.  That isn't a part of the solution code.

Comment: Thanks, did a little change. Instead of `document.write` is there a way to append XML in IE7? At the moment its writing the XML but its encapsulated in `"<xml>"`

Comment: Where are you trying to append the XML?  If you want to select everything inside the XML, you can do `var commands = document.getElementsByTagName("commands")[0];`.  If you want to append it to the document directly, you can do `document.append(commands);`.  The problem is, once you do that, the only way you will be able to see the XML is by inspecting the page.

Comment: Not trying to select a value from XML, trying to render the XML in DOM on IE7. `.append(xml)` works fine on latest browsers.

Comment: I edited the snippet to show appending the XML to the DOM along with a screenshot.  This should work fine in IE7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136265/discussion-between-mrnew-and-damian-t).

Comment: I have similar one already document.getElementById().appendChild(xml), what's `[0]` is for however still getting `Object doesn't support property or method append` even on IE11

Comment: Sorry I meant even on ie9

Comment: I responded [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136265/discussion-between-mrnew-and-damian-t).

Comment: replied in chat

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty.

```
var gen = function() {
    var jObj = {"Smart Shoes":{"Product":"Smart Shoes","Price":24.99,"Quantity":"1x "},"Denim Jeans":{"Product":"Denim Jeans","Price":30,"Quantity":"1x "}}
    var xmlString = '<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true"><commands><injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR"/>';

    for (var item in jObj) {
      if (jObj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        xmlString += '<injectdata type="literal" data="' + jObj[item].Price + '"/>'; // I don't know where you got UPC from
        xmlString += '<injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC"/>'
      }
    }

    xmlString += '</commands></xml>';

    console.log(xmlString);
}
```

This will produce valid XML like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true">
   <commands>
      <injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR" />
      <injectdata type="literal" data="24.99" />
      <injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC" />
      <injectdata type="literal" data="30" />
      <injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC" />
   </commands>
</xml>
```

I would, however suggest **converting** your objects/arrays to xml.